# How do I control my callbacks in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, callback, passport.js, sequelize.js, control-flow

so I'm working on an application written in CoffeeScript and I'm using Sequelize as an ORM for my application. I'm at a stage where I'm integrating Passport.js. However the part I'm having issues with is getting the user out of the database when trying to authenticate. I know that the issue is that the function is returning before the Sequelize function I have written has had a chance to return but I can't figure out how to control the flow properly.

Here is the code I've got so far:
User model

```
exports.getUserByUsername = (username, callback) ->
User.findOne({
    where : {
     username : username
    }}, (err, user) ->
    console.log 'hello?'
    return callback(err) if err
    return callback(undefined, user) if user
)
```

Hello doesn't get called so that's step 1 of knowing it's returning too soon. Then in my verification callback inside the passport strategy I have this:

```
(username, password, done) ->
    ChatModel.getUserByUsername username, (err, user) ->
        console.log 2
        return done err if err
        return done null, false, message: 'Incorrect user' if not user

        if ChatModel.isValidPassword user, password then return done null, user
    console.log 1
```

Again, the "1" is logged to the console and "2" is never logged which must mean that it's returning. Can someone tell me how I should be controlling the flow of execution?

Thank you in advance if you can help.

Comment: Take a look to `async` module. The method `waterfall` seems what you need https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Doesn't matter what solution you use, async, promises, but you're going to have to get a handle on taking care of your callbacks.

Comment: Agreed with Robert, you need to spend some time getting a handle on async control flow before you use a further abstraction to clean up your code. As a general guiding rule to keep in your head, move any 'dependent' code into the callback function of the code that it is depending on.